# Trouble Starting MongoDB (Mac) - Code: 100

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I installed MongoDB via Homebrew and seem to be having some trouble starting when I run the mongod command. I have tried setting a up the data/db directory correctly and viewed a few other answers on stackoverflow, but haven't been able to figure this out. Here is what I keep getting (sorry I am new to this):

```
    2017-01-02T23:45:53.444-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1419 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Johns-MacBook-Pro-3.local
2017-01-02T23:45:53.445-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.0
2017-01-02T23:45:53.445-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: f4240c60f005be757399042dc12f6addbc3170c1
2017-01-02T23:45:53.445-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
2017-01-02T23:45:53.445-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2017-01-02T23:45:53.445-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-01-02T23:45:53.445-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-01-02T23:45:53.445-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-01-02T23:45:53.445-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-01-02T23:45:53.445-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-01-02T23:45:53.446-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=7680M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2017-01-02T23:45:53.447-0500 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (2) [1483418753:447985][1419:0x7fffe84c03c0], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: No such file or directory
2017-01-02T23:45:53.457-0500 I -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:2: No such file or directory src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 267
2017-01-02T23:45:53.458-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28595 2: No such file or directory, terminating
2017-01-02T23:45:53.458-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-01-02T23:45:53.458-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2017-01-02T23:45:53.458-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-01-02T23:45:53.458-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-01-02T23:45:53.458-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

Comment: What have you investigated? A quick search [this](https://gist.github.com/satoryu/495913e59bb249b060cc) description was found.

Comment: Make sure directory `/data/db` exists and MonoDB has permission to access it

Answer (score 0):

Just create directory - `/data/db/` on system hdd

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: `sudo mongod --dbpath ~/data/db`