# (Mac) Cannot start mongo, via "mongod" command

Tags: mongodb, macos

Just trying to get up and started using the "mongod" command...

I've already looked at the following:
[Cannot start mongo db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744961/cannot-start-mongo-db)
[Trouble Starting MongoDB (Mac) - Code: 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41436638/trouble-starting-mongodb-mac-code-100)
... and many other forum posts.

This is what I got in my terminal:

```
#####-MacBook-Pro-2:p2w4-back_end ashesmachine$ mongod
2020-05-17T13:53:02.341-0700 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-05-17T13:53:02.345-0700 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
2020-05-17T13:53:02.346-0700 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=57712 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=#####-MacBook-Pro-2.local
2020-05-17T13:53:02.346-0700 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.6
2020-05-17T13:53:02.346-0700 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 20364840b8f1af16917e4c23c1b5f5efd8b352f8
2020-05-17T13:53:02.346-0700 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2020-05-17T13:53:02.346-0700 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-05-17T13:53:02.346-0700 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-05-17T13:53:02.346-0700 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-05-17T13:53:02.346-0700 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-05-17T13:53:02.346-0700 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2020-05-17T13:53:02.346-0700 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2020-05-17T13:53:02.347-0700 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2020-05-17T13:53:02.347-0700 I  -        [initandlisten] Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.
2020-05-17T13:53:02.347-0700 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2020-05-17T13:53:02.347-0700 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

Comment: The problem is literally spelled out for you in the log:  `NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found`

Comment: Right, I've actually already tried troubleshooting. Creating this pathway doesn't work with the "mkdir -p /data/db" command, or even with the sudo command...

Comment: Find your mongod.conf file.  Typically on osx it would be in `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf ` but your installation doesn't seem to reflect a typical install.  Try starting mongod specifying the path to the config file:  `mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` or whatever the path to the mongod.conf is.

Comment: Check the mongod.conf for the `dbPath: ` variable.  Set that to a known directory your user has access to.  For example you could make a directory in your home dir named `mongo_data`.  cd into that directory and run `pwd`.  Set the dpPath in the mongod.conf file to be the path to the directory you just created and try starting mongod.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the data/db directory before starting mongodb. Something like `mkdir -p /data/db`

Comment: Yes, I've tried this and I get the following error: "mkdir: /data/db: Read-only file system", even if I use "sudo"

Comment: What does that mean? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo mongod --dbpath ~/Documents/data/mongo-db
```